# What is 'type' in Python?

Tags: python

```
>>> type(type)
<type 'type'>
```

I expect the type of `type` to be a function since it's used to return the type of the argument. Does this mean a type can accept arguments? Is `type` something unusual/special?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`type` is a *metaclass*: a class whose instances are also classes. The type of any other builtin class will also be `type` - eg:

```
>>> type(object)
<class 'type'>
>>> type(list)
<class 'type'>
```

Indeed, every (new-style) class will also be an instance of `type`, although if it is defined with a custom metaclass, `type(my_class)` will be that metaclass. But since every metaclass is required to inherit from `type`, you will have, for any class:

```
>>> isinstance(my_class, type)
True
```

Answer (score 4):

Classes are objects. All objects are instances of a class. So since a class is an object, it is an instance of some class. The class that a class is an instance of is named `type`. It is the base [metaclass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/100003/what-is-a-metaclass-in-python).

Originally `type()` was just a function that returned an object's class. In Python 2.2, user-defined classes and built-in types were [unified](https://www.python.org/download/releases/2.2/descrintro/), and `type` became a class. For backward compatibility, it still behaves like the old `type()` function when called with one argument.

Answer (score 1):

`type` is Python's class ur-type. When called with a single argument it returns the type of the argument. When called with 3 arguments it returns a class whose characteristics are determined by the arguments.

Comment: @user2864740: It's the type of all other types.

Answer (score 1):

As can be clearly seen in the [documentations](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#type) -

> **class type(object)**
> **class type(name, bases, dict)**
>
> With one argument, return the type of an object. The return value is a type object. The isinstance() built-in function is recommended for testing the type of an object.

`type` is a class, not a function.